# What is the purpose of a valve on a dry bag?

Tags: gear

[This dry bag](https://www.ortlieb.com/en/Compression%20dry%20bag%20with%20valve%20and%20belt/) comes with a valve and compression straps.  I understand the purpose of the compression bag, but what is the purpose of a valve?

Comment: I think the question is sensible. Most dry bags don't have such a valve, so it's worth asking what's special about the ones that do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Letting the air out while you're closing/compressing the bag, looks like.

It's probably more of a risk than a benefit in general, but could be worth considering if you need to pack tight around hard objects or edges, like having gear for a multi day trip inside a kayak.

Alternatively, you could use it as a water bag with tap, but it does not look like that's the intended function.

Answer (score 8):

A further reason is to use the space in the bag for buoyancy and to squeeze the bag into a space securely, by adding air to the bag after it's in place. This generally means a valve on a tube.

Comment: Interesting — it did not occur to me that kayakers may *want* air in their dry-bags.  I'm always trying (and failing) to squeeze every last bit out!

Comment: Mine don't have valves, but some people I paddle with use those that do and they at least partly replace air bags in WW kayaks.